# How to display ads for each country in (Django GeoIP)

Tags: django, view, geoip

I'm trying to show different ads in each country, Example, SPAIN display Adsense and CO display yieldmanager.

My views and templates:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
class VideoViewDetail(DetailView):
    model = Video

    def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(Video, slug__exact=self.kwargs['slug'])

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VideoViewDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            g = GeoIP()
            ip = self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            country = g.country('ip')
            context['country_name'] = country
        return context

template
{% for video in objectc_list %}
    {{ video.name }} | {{ video.genre.name }}
    {% if country_name == 'ES' %}
        **code here ads**
    {% else %}
        {% if country_name == 'CO' %}
            **code here ads**
        {% else %}
            {% if country_name == 'MX' %}
                **code here ads**
            {% else %}
               ** nothing **
    {% endif %}
```

Something I'm doing wrong that does not work, I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With their native PHP library and the GeoIP.dat dataset, this is how it's done:

```
// Open GeoIP database and get the visitor's location.
$geoIP = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$visitorLocation = geoip_record_by_addr($geoIP, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
$visitorCountry = $visitorLocation->country_code;

// Decide whether to show AdSense or not.
// In this example, we show it only to visitors from the U.S.A., Canada and the United Kingdom.
if (in_array($visitorCountry, array("us", "ca", "gb")))
{
    // Show AdSense!
    // ...
}
else
{
    // Show some other ad we don't care about so much.
    // ...
}
```